# How to test all the links in footer of any given webpage

Tags: python, selenium

I want to test all the link in a footer section of any given webpage.

Ex:

```
<footer id="globalfooter">
 <a href="www.abc.com/xyz">
 <div>
  <a href="www.google.com/abc">
 </div>
 <div>
  <a href="www.linkedin.com/abc">
 </div>
<a href="www.facebook.com/abc">
</footer>
```

the program should return all the 4 links in the footer section.
I appreciate all the given help in advance.

This is the code I have tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

chrome_path = "/Users/tanmaykale/Downloads/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

# -----------Getting footer content of apple.com------------

driver.get("http://www.apple.com")
footer = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('footer')
print footer
elems = footer.find_element_by_tag_name('div')
linkscount = len(elems)
print "Total No of link in footer of www.apple.com are : ",linkscount
```

The code returns the following:

linkscount = len(elems)
TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()

Comment: Have you tried to implement something yourself? Have a go and then ask specific questions about any problems that you had. SO is not a coding service.

Comment: And what do you mean by "test"? Should the URLs be extracted? Should the resource be downloaded? What?

Comment: @mhawke i have tried my own code. I edited the initial question

I want to get all the hrefs in a string so that I can pass it to another function which makes a request and fetches the status codes.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. Please don't be so presumptuous.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you got confused with **find_element_by_tag_name** and **find_elements_by_tag_name** methods.

**Find_element_by_tag_name** returns only one element (typically the first element) in the selection, whereas **find_elements_by_tag_name** returns list of all elements that were available in the page/selection.

Changing any one in below should resolve the issue.

```
links = footer.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
links = footer.find_elements_by_css_selector('a')
links = footer.find_elements_by.xpath('.//a')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.
i tried extracting all the a href in the footer section by using the following:
elems = footer.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
But it returns a href from the entire webpage.
what can I do to extract href's from the footer only?
Thank you in advance

Comment: @TanmayK can you try footer.find_elements_by_tag_name('a') ?

Comment: Should be `elems = footer.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a[@href]")`,  Missed a dot at beginning of xpath.